# Write to / in / into a file

Tags: prepositions, terminology

Which of these sentences are correct:

> We need to write this data to a file.
>   We need to write this data in a file.
>   We need to write this data into a file.

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a British programmer I would say "to" sounds the most natural and common, but all three of them make a certain amount of sense and I would not like to declare the other options "incorrect".  I think computer science / IT is far too new for the English language to have developed a single, unarguably "correct" answer to this question.